# how to enable the user to choose a picture from his own wp7 library and place it in the xna game?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

In my XNA-Game I want to provide the oppertunity to take a picutre with the camera of the phone or choose a picture of the memory. how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a list of images/pictures from the device you can use the [MediaLibrary.Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx) Property.

If you don't want to create the UI for choosing an image or you want to allow the user to take a picture with the camera check out the [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask%28VS.92%29.aspx) and [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).